# VS 2019 ASP.Net core solution with several web projects starts in wrong working directory

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a c# asp.net core (3.1 if it matters) solution that holds two different web solutions.

When I first open the solution and debug it normally, the "main" project works just fine: I can run it in the debugger and work with it.

However, as soon as I run the second project (an admin control panel for the main app) from the IDE once, the working directory gets somehow "cooked" to the path of the second project and nothing seems to be able to change it back. This causes the main application to fail because it can't find its configuration and startup files (it finds the one of the second project).

Restarting the IDE solves the problem until I run or debug the second application as well.

I tried printing the current directory to the debug console as first line of the application and, indeed, I get the root path of the wrong project:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.Print(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

I have tried to force the working directory in the project options to the absolute path pf the debug binaries as a temporary fix but this does not change the behavior at all.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Do you debug using IISExpress or the project itself? And have you checked the project files for some configuration problems?

Comment: Yes, I'm debugging using IIS express and yes, I have checked the project files for any obvious configuration issue.